# Selecting features using an attribute which falls within a range

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, expression, select

I want to select batches of features using an expression which gives a range of IDs to select.

Instead of writing this
`"ID" IN (1,2,3,4,5)` I would like to write something like this `"ID" IN (1:5)`

I tried the following but they didn't work:

`"ID" IN (generate_series(1,5,1))`

`"ID" IN (array_to_string(generate_series(1,5,1)))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this ?

```
array_find(generate_series(1,5),"ID")>0
```

Comment: This is close! Thank you. I was hoping that there was an operator like ' : ' that I just didn't know about but this is good too!

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
"ID" <= 5 AND  "ID" >= 1
```

Comment: I must be having a pretty slow day because I didn't think of this. It's not exactly what I'm looking for but thank you!